# Using Proc sql to get statiscs for many variables

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I want to use Porc sql to create a data set that contains some statistics as min and max for a lots of variables. The code below only returns a data set with min and max for first variable, for the rest of variables min and max are not show in the data set.

```
  proc sql;
  CREATE TABLE Lib.VarNum AS 
  %do i=1 %to &nvars;
  select  min(%SCAN(&numvar,&i)) as Min%SCAN(&numvar,&i),
     max(%SCAN(&numvar,&i)) as Max%SCAN(&numvar,&i)
  from &data (keep= _numeric_);
  %end;
  quit;
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: For code that's is not working you really need to provide the full code as well as an explanation of what is not working. However, in general, PROC MEANS is significantly faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using proc means is best way to do this.

```
  proc means data=sashelp.cars noprint;
 var _numeric_;
 output out=want (drop= _type_ _freq_ )min(_numeric_) =
 max(_numeric_) =/autoname;
 run;
```

but if you want to so it by Proc SQL easiest to macrovariables from dictionary.columns and use them in your tables.

```
 /* creating macrovariables using dictionary.columns*/
 proc sql noprint;
select 'min('|| trim(name)||') as min_'||name,
   'max('|| trim(name)||') as max_'||name 
   into :min separated by ',' , :max separated by ','
from dictionary.columns
where libname ='SASHELP'
and memname ='CARS'
and upcase(type) ='NUM';
```

Values of macrovariable can be checkedly and only partially shown

```
 %put &min;
  min(MSRP) as min_MSRP,min(Invoice) as min_Invoice,min(EngineSize) as min_EngineSize
```

use this macro variables in proc sql statement as shown below.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select &min, &max from sashelp.cars;
```

Comment: Thanks I will do it with proc means